# How to make VS Code autocomplete classes and methods from the UnityEngine library?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use VS Code to write scripts for Unity and I can't get the editor to autocomplete any of the classes from UnityEngine. I'm trying to get something like this https://youtu.be/nWuekr5rUcg?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0fnA91TcmkRyhhixX9CO3Lw&t=397

I've already added the Unity Snippets and the MonoBehavior extensions to VS Code and neither of those has worked.

I've also followed this guide https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity and nothing has changed.

I'm out of ideas of what I can try to fix here

Comment: Do you have vscode opened to the Unity Project itself? You should start the project from the unity editor, and ```open folder``` in vscode, not just the file.

Comment: when you start ```VS Code``` from Unity check the Output Window, it might help you to find out what is going wrong. ```Ctrl + Shift + U``` or ```View > Output``` to open the Output window

Comment: @EricChen1248 I am opening from the editor and VS is showing the entire project on the files tab. I read about that detail before asking on other forums, but that didn't fix my problem

Comment: @Ankit I can't find anything wrong in the output window. I think my problem is coming from VS code not knowing the specific file location for the UnityEngine library in my computers, because it never references it. It only knows not to complain of the objects or methods I call on other objects after I write them, but it can't autocomplete them for me.

Comment: That's weird, the UnityEngine Library should be in the same folder as the project, so it shouldn't need to "know" where it is. Do you also have the C# extension installed as well? If so, check the output on the Omnisharp tab, and/or try restarting Omnisharp through the command pallette

Comment: Did you set your changed your editor in ```Edit > Preference > External Tools``` menu.